# Using a randomly generated folder name in a directory tree?

Tags: variables, random, batch-file, directory

I am trying to make a single batch file to both backup and restore cookies for my favorite online game, but ran into a problem when trying to navigate past the randomly-named folder Chrome uses to house its cookies.

I tried using the `FOR` command to get a variable that would give me the name of the folder, and then I would use the variable later in the directories. The variable worked fine when `ECHO`'d, but then became `%G` when put into the directory.

At first I put in my code, but it was an ugly block of text, so here's just a sampling:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /B /AD "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot\#SharedObjects"') DO (
echo %%G )
```

This returned an echo of the correct folder name :)

But when I used `%%G` in a directory:

```
copy "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot\#SharedObjects\%%G\chat.kongregate.com\antiIdle_file0" "%HOMEPATH%\My Documents\Anti-Idle backup\antiIdle_file0.sol" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
```

When testing the variable with ECHO in front of it, `%%G` shows up as `%G` instead of the random string of numbers that should show up as.

If I am doing something wrong, please critique me. If you have a suggestion or an alternate way to handle this, please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that this is what's wrong, but you can shorten your paths a lot by using `%LOCALAPPDATA%` instead of `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local`.  Or if you want XP compatibility, `%TEMP%\..\Google\etc`.  :) More info on [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the folder in one part of your code and use it elsewhere, you can use the `for` loop to set another variable, and use that other one for the copy later.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /B /AD "...your path..."') DO (
    SET FolderPath=%%G
)
```

... and elsewhere:

```
COPY "...source file..." "%FolderPath%"
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me just the answer I was looking for. :)
Gave me enough maneuverability to add extra features to it too, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

`%%G` is only valid in the context of the `FOR`hence you need to include your `COPY` command between the parentheses following the `DO`

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (
'dir ...blahblahblah...SharedObjects"') DO (
echo %%G
copy "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\...blah..SharedObjects\%%G\...zzzz...file0" "%HOMEPATH%...etc.._file0.sol" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
)
```

Obviously, the `echo %%G` is optional.
(it's OK to break the command into separate lines - with care. Critical that the open-parenthesis is on the same line as the DO )

Another way is

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (
 'dir ...blahblahblah...SharedObjects"') DO set "target=%%G"
copy "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\...blah..SharedObjects\%TARGET%\...zzzz...file0" "%HOMEPATH%...etc.._file0.sol" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
```

Noting that the CASE of the metavariable(`%%G`) is critical, but the name and case of `TARGET` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a recursive search for `chat.kongregate.com`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a:d "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\*chat.kongregate.com"') do (
    copy /d /y "%%I\antiIdle_file0" "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Anti-Idle backup\antiIdle_file0.sol"
)
```